# What does sp_CONFIGURE 'Database Mail XPs', 1 do

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to configure email on SQL server one of commands I am supposed to run [according to this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/)

```
sp_CONFIGURE 'Database Mail XPs', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on what does `sp_CONFIGURE 'Database Mail XPs', 1` do, I understand that `1` enables something but **what is being enabled exactly?**

Comment: Try google for `database mail xps sp_configure`? https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=database%20mail%20xps%20sp_configure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @NickyvV.

[According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191189.aspx) it Enables the Database Mail extended stored procedures in the msdb database.

Setting the Database Mail XPs option to 0 prevents Database Mail from starting. If it is running when the option is set to 0, it continues to run and send mail until it is idle for the time configured in the DatabaseMailExeMinimumLifeTime option.